# Rails Invalid request parameters: Invalid encoding for parameter with backticks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hope someone can lend some insight here. Getting some rails errors for:

> Invalid request parameters: Invalid encoding for parameter: Breaking Up Was Easy In The 90�s

This happens when I recieve POST data containing backticks. Example would be a song title or artist that someone used a backtick instead of an apostrophe like this:

```
{
  "TITLE": "Breaking Up Was Easy In The 90`s",
  "ARTIST": "Sam Hunt"
}
```

All my searching is coming up with fixing rails query parameters, not request parameters. Is there a middleware solution I can use to intercept this and fix it?

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this with my Rails 6.1 app on ruby 3.0.0 using Postgres 12.6 and I do not have any issues with backticks in string parameters. What version of Rails and ruby do you use?

Comment: It's 6.0. I'm starting to think its an actual encoding issue and not really and issue with the backtick...gonna try and force the encoding on the params and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry,. it actually is 6.1. Had two code bases opened up and looked at wrong one.

Comment: What encoding is being sent by the client? Its decided by the `Content-Type` header if I remeber correctly.

Comment: application/json is the Content-Type. I still haven't figured a good fix, but added [Rack::UTF8Sanitizer](https://github.com/whitequark/rack-utf8_sanitizer/) to keep it from generating errors for now.

Comment: @fcamp thats just the MIME, clients can also specify encodings with for example `Content-Type: application/json; charset=iso-8859-1`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Answer (score 0):

You can rescue from this error using StandardError Expection

(Since every error & exception class inherits from StandardError it is sufficient to Rescue)

```
    rescue StandardError => e
      // get that Title string in a variable and use
      Title.gsub('`', ''')
    end
```